# Is this number $N$ a new mathematical constant?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Smallest real number $N$ such that the equation $2^x = Nx$ has solution in real number $x$. I have calculated $N$ up to 9 digit precision , $N= 1.88416938....$, I believe $N$ converges. Has this constant $N$ been found by someone and been given a name ??. Can you verify that my calculation correct?

Comment: Yes, it is known. It equals `E Log[2]`. Tightly connected to `ProductLog`.

Answer (score 6):

```
min = Minimize[{n, 2^x == n*x, n > 0}, {n, x}]

(* {E Log[2], {n -> E Log[2], x -> 1/Log[2]}} *)

min[[1]] // N[#, 50] &

(* 1.8841693853637201099021591169254013346972650564547 *)
```

**EDIT:** Graphically,

```
ContourPlot[2^x == n*x, {n, 1, 3}, {x, 0, 3},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Tooltip[Point[{n, x}], {n, x}] /. min[[2]]},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {n, x})]
```

[image]